# javascript and element location

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I want to get up to speed on element location and javascript.

ie. if someone clicks on an element, I can show a menu just below that element.

Now I realize I have to account for the fact that if someone clicks on a element to the extreme left/right or bottom of the page, I have to know if the menu is visible on the screen properly.

This seems complicated and would love if there is some tutorial on this very topic?

Answer (score 3):

This will help:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Answer (score 2):

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+context+menu) yielded this result for a [`Prototype.js` context menu](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/scripting/contextMenu/). It looks to be exactly what you're looking for.